# DatePicker: how to customize

Tags: java, datepicker, javafx

I have the simple code for date picker which disables all the dates which are before the chosen one, but I need to be able to disable other dates as well (like for example:17.10.2014 until 19.10.2014). How could I change it in a way that specific dates are also disabled?

```
public class DatePickerSample extends Application {

private Stage stage;
private DatePicker checkInDatePicker;
private DatePicker checkOutDatePicker;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);                  
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    this.stage = stage;
    stage.setTitle("DatePickerSample ");
    initUI();
    stage.show();
}

private void initUI() {
    VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
    vbox.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;");
    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 400, 400);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    checkInDatePicker = new DatePicker();
    checkOutDatePicker = new DatePicker();
    checkInDatePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
    final Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = 
        new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {
            @Override
            public DateCell call(final DatePicker datePicker) {
                return new DateCell() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (item.isBefore(
                                checkInDatePicker.getValue().plusDays(1))
                            ) {
                                setDisable(true);
                                setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffc0cb;");
                        }
                        long p = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(
                                checkInDatePicker.getValue(), item
                        );
                        setTooltip(new Tooltip(
                            "You're about to stay for " + p + " days")
                        );
                }
            };
        }
    };
    checkOutDatePicker.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory);
    checkOutDatePicker.setValue(checkInDatePicker.getValue().plusDays(1));
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

    gridPane.setHgap(10);
    gridPane.setVgap(10);
    Label checkInlabel = new Label("Check-In Date:");
    gridPane.add(checkInlabel, 0, 0);
    GridPane.setHalignment(checkInlabel, HPos.LEFT);
    gridPane.add(checkInDatePicker, 0, 1);
    Label checkOutlabel = new Label("Check-Out Date:");
    gridPane.add(checkOutlabel, 0, 2);
    GridPane.setHalignment(checkOutlabel, HPos.LEFT);
    gridPane.add(checkOutDatePicker, 0, 3);
    vbox.getChildren().add(gridPane);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to have several ranges of dates to disable, you can create this POJO:

```
class DisabledRange {

    private final LocalDate initialDate;
    private final LocalDate endDate;

    public DisabledRange(LocalDate initialDate, LocalDate endDate){
        this.initialDate=initialDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public LocalDate getInitialDate() { return initialDate; }
    public LocalDate getEndDate() { return endDate; }

}
```

And now in you can define a collection of ranges to disable in your calendar. For instance:

```
private final ObservableList<DisabledRange> rangesToDisable = 
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new DisabledRange(LocalDate.of(2014,10,17), LocalDate.of(2014,10,19)),
        new DisabledRange(LocalDate.of(2014,10,27), LocalDate.of(2014,10,29)));
```

Finally, you just need to check in the `Callback` if the `item` is within any of these ranges:

```
@Override
public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    boolean disable = rangesToDisable.stream()
            .filter(r->r.initialDate.minusDays(1).isBefore(item))
            .filter(r->r.endDate.plusDays(1).isAfter(item))
            .findAny()
            .isPresent();

    if (item.isBefore(checkInDatePicker.getValue().plusDays(1)) || 
            disable) {
            setDisable(true);
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffc0cb;");
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: sorry just cant understand the annotation here.. from where it supposed to call the super..or maybe i couldnt understand the code at all..because i think all this belongs to class DisabledRange and whenever i need i need to make a instance of DisabledRange and then give the dates that i want to cancel..or did i understood all wrong :(

Comment: `DisabledRange` it's just a wrapper of two dates, useful to build a list of posible ranges of dates to be disabled in the calendar... I've just added this list to the `updateItem` method of the `Callback`. Every time you display the popup, for each `item` (which is one of the days shown), we check if it is found in any of those ranges, in order to set its style as disabled, like you already did disabling all dates previous to the initial date. We're simply overriding the update method for every cell to enable/disable days as you requested on the first place.