# how to customize datepicker in javaFX so that I can restrict the user to not be able to choose any date which is a monday

Tags: javafx

I need to customize my date picker so that it does not accept any dates on certain days of the week.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javafx datepicker how to customize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330348/javafx-datepicker-how-to-customize)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 9):

If you are OK with the user not being able to type in the text field, you can make the date picker non-editable, and use a cell factory to disable the cells displaying Mondays:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.DateCell;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class IDontLikeMondays extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
        datePicker.setDayCellFactory(picker -> new DateCell() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(date, empty);
                setDisable(empty || date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
            }
        });
        datePicker.setEditable(false);

        StackPane root = new StackPane(datePicker);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

If you want the date picker to still be editable, you have to come up with some strategy for handling the possibility that the user types in a date that represents a Monday. For example, the following uses a `converter` that just moves Mondays back to the preceding Sunday:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.DateCell;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;
import javafx.util.converter.LocalDateStringConverter;

public class IDontLikeMondays extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
        datePicker.setDayCellFactory(picker -> new DateCell() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(date, empty);
                setDisable(empty || date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
            }
        });

        StringConverter<LocalDate> converter = new LocalDateStringConverter() {
            @Override
            public LocalDate fromString(String string) {
                LocalDate date = super.fromString(string);
                if (date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.MONDAY) {
                    return date.minusDays(1);
                } else {
                    return date ;
                }
            }
        };
        datePicker.setConverter(converter);


        StackPane root = new StackPane(datePicker);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Also note that the `DatePicker` handles exceptions thrown by the converter by reverting to the previous value, so you could also do:

```
StringConverter<LocalDate> converter = new LocalDateStringConverter() {
    @Override
    public LocalDate fromString(String string) {
        LocalDate date = super.fromString(string);
        if (date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.MONDAY) {

            throw new IllegalStateException("I don't like Mondays");

        } else {
            return date ;
        }
    }
};
datePicker.setConverter(converter);
```

and in this case if the user typed in a date representing a Monday, it would simply reject it and revert to the current value.

In general, I would recommend making the date picker non-editable, as I think that gives more intuitive behavior to the user.