# How to stop JavaFX Alert from opening multiple alerts?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I believe I have encountered a bug within the JavaFX API, but I'm not sure. So the following snippet behaves normally, but when I add an `alert.show();` or `alert.showAndWait();`, the program opens three different alert dialogues. Here's the code:

```
    private void datePickerOnHiding(JFXDatePicker datePicker, JFXCheckBox chkBox) { 
        int counter = 0;
        boolean entered = false;

        if (datePicker.getValue().isBefore(LocalDate.now()) ||datePicker.getValue().isEqual(LocalDate.now())) {
            if ((eventHiddenCounter % 2) == 0) {
                System.out.println("HAHA");//Testing
                txtfMessage.setVisible(true);
                txtfMessage.setText("Please select a future date.");
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING, "Please select a future date.");
                alert.showAndWait();
                datePicker.setValue(null);

                counter ++;
                entered = true;
            }
        } else {
            txtfMessage.setVisible(false);
            chkBox.setSelected(true);
        }

        //Testing
        System.out.println("" + eventHiddenCounter + ": " + ((eventHiddenCounter % 2) == 0));
        System.out.println("COUNTER: " + counter + "\nENTERED: " + entered);
        entered = false;
        eventHiddenCounter ++;
}
```

Here's the ouput with the `alert.showAndWait` commented out:

> HAHA
>   0: true
>   COUNTER: 1
>   ENTERED: true

Here it is with it included (the bug):

> HAHA
>   HAHA
>   HAHA
>   0: true
>   COUNTER: 1
>   ENTERED: true
>   1: false
>   COUNTER: 1
>   ENTERED: true
>   2: true
>   COUNTER: 1
>   ENTERED: true

I am quite perplexed--why is this happening, and what can I do to get around it?

By the way, the goal is to prevent the user from picking a date equal to or before the current day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jai's answer is helpful, but I just disabled the days I didn't want using DayCells.

See:
http://o7planning.org/en/11085/javafx-datepicker-tutorial
[javafx datepicker how to customize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330348/javafx-datepicker-how-to-customize)

I used the first one.

Edit: **I figured out what was causing the repetition.**

The focus shifts in the scene after the Alert dialogue is closed in the closing event listener. I have a similar (read: same) dialogue for a focus-lost listener (they fire under the same conditions), so the dialogues appeared to be the same, despite having different origins. Essentially, the focus kept oscillating to and from the node with the focus listener, causing numerous Alert popups for one error.

I realized my mistake after changing the AlertType of the closing listener Alert.

Simple fix - I made an `externalRequest` boolean flag, and I changed the `focusListener` event handler to do nothing if the `externalRequest` flag was true. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The date picker creates a popup and your alert is also a popup window.

The most likely reason (I can't be sure because I have no idea how `datePickerOnHiding()` is being called) is that the two popups are having race condition. When you try to show the alert, you are triggering the `datePickerOnHiding()` because it is trying to hide again.

If you want to stop user from selecting invalid values, you need to trigger this method **after** the datepicker popup is already closed (i.e. hidden).

Comment: I can confirm that this isn't limited to date pickers. I'm having the same issue when using alerts during a closing event. This time, I dragged the Alert around to find another right behind it. Curious, and I'm pretty sure this is an API bug at this point.

Comment: Wait I'll rescind that statement.  

Turns out, the focus shifted after the Alert dialogue was closed in the closing event listener. I have a very similar dialogue for a focus-lost listener, hence I thought they were the same.  

I realized my mistake after changing the AlertType of the closing listener Alert.

Comment: @PujitM I actually got quite lost on what you have been talking about. As far as I know, your problem would probably be gone if you used `onHidden` event instead of `onHiding` event. This is because you have used a blocking `Alert` and that alert is trying to make sure its parent window is visible. This probably caused the combobox to receive another request to hide while it is still in `hiding` state.